# Invalidate session after 3 login attempt

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, session

I am trying to invalidate session after 3 unsuccessful attempt. Scenario is like after 3 invalid attempt it should redirect another page and invalidate the session but after 3rd invalid attempt its invalidating the session then creating again.
i am using counter to invalidate session. my code and its description below:

**$.post("/tssac/app/reAuthenticate/validateSignature", {

   'count':vcount
}).done ;**

through post i am trying to hit spring MVC controller .In which i am passing count as a session attribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validateSignature", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validatePortalDigitalSignature(

@RequestParam(required = false, value = "count") String count, ModelMap map) throws Exception {

    map.put("count",0);
    if (!SUCCESS_RESPONSE_CODES.contains(portalServiceResponse)) {
        map.put("error", true);
    }
    return "jsonView";
```

then i am checking for count and and based on that i am rendering to another page.

```
   function invalidAttempts() {
    count++;
    if (count == 3) {
        count = 0;
        $.post("/tssac/app/reAuthenticate/forceLogOff", {});
    }
```

but its not invalidating the session . i am not able to store my count variable in session , please help me through this.

Comment: surely if the user hasn't logged in yet they haven't really got a session worth keeping? What exactly in the session do you want to destroy at that time?

Comment: like if  i am doing one invalid login attempt the close the page and again if i come and do invalid login the count should increase to 2 .but its coming count as 1.

Comment: destroying session means it rendering to some other page so my count should come to 0 because we have invalidated the session.

Comment: ok well count appears like it is not stored on the server, rather you keep track of it on the client and then send it to the server (where I can't see much evidence of you saving it into a session) so it's not really a session value as far as I can see. It helps to use the correct terminology. And $.post does not "render to another page", it makes an ajax request. That will not cause your code to leave the current page. If you want to navigate to another page use `window.location.href = "http:/www.example.com";` instead.

Comment: And why would you redirect the user to a "forceLogOff" page if they're not already logged in? That doesn't make much sense. Also, when they come back to your login page next time (a few seconds later, maybe) can they have another 3 turns? How long until they should be allowed to try again? Or must they do some kind of unlock process? I ask because your count is only tracked in the JS right now, so it will just reset to 0 when they refresh the page, by the look of it. Is your problem that you don't know how you should track this value server-side? Or what?

Comment: yeah you are right . so if you please tell me how to store count on server side .  thanks in  advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156536/discussion-between-gaurav-ranjan-and-adyson).

Comment: sorry, I can't actually help you with that because I don't know Spring. I found the question due to the ajax tag. If you edit your question contents to make clear what you require, then perhaps a spring expert will come along an answer it. (If you edit the question, it goes back to the top of the homepage, so more chance someone will see it).